# Find a polynomial $p$ of degree $3$ such that $-1,2$,and $3$ are zeroes of $p$ and $p(0)=1$ where book solution lacks rigour.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, solution-verification, irreducible-polynomials

Of course, I considered $p(x) = (x+1)(x-2)(x-3)$, but it is clear that $p(0) \neq 1$. A bit stumped by this I see that the book solution says that we MUST have $p(x) = c(x+1)(x-2)(x-3)$ for some $c$. I understand why this is an idea to get to a polynomial that satisfies the conditions. What I don't understand is how it is obvious $p(x)$ MUST be of this form. If I knew this I believe I would have considered this idea on my own.

Is there a rigorous argument to see why $p(x)$ MUST be able to be reduced in this way (preferably using only precalculus knowledge)?

Comment: ANY polynomial of degree exactly $3$ and $-1,2,3$ as roots is of the form $c(x+1)(x-2)(x+3)$, with $c\ne0$.

Comment: And you think it is rigorous to simply state it as fact?

Comment: It is so obvious...

Comment: There are so many ways to write a polynomial that is it truely not immediately clear why this is the case. What makes you think literally repeating what I ask, and then saying "it is obvious" is useful in any way?

Comment: If $a$ is a root of the polynomial, then $(x-a)$ is a factor. This leads immediately to the claim.

Comment: A polynomial can always be written as a product of degree 1 polynomials involving its roots. Consider $ p(x) = a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3) $. Expanding the parentheses you get the other general form $ p(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d $ where $ b,c,d $ will depend on $ a,x_1,x_2,x_3 $. If you leave out $ a $ by fixing it to 1 then you will always get the normalized polynomial $ x^3 + \tilde bx^2 + \tilde c x + \tilde d $ (the tilde here to indicate that $ \tilde b $ will be different from the $ b $ above). So it is perfectly reasonable to introduce $ a $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $-1$, $2$, and $3$ are roots of $p(x)$ and that $\deg p(x)=3$. Divide $p(x)$ by $(x+1)(x-2)(x-3)$; you will get$$p(x)=(x+1)(x-2)(x-3)q(x)+r(x)$$where $\deg r(x)<3$. But then since $\deg p(x)=3$, $\deg q(x)=0$; that is, $q(x)=c$, for some constant $c$. So, you have$$p(x)=c(x+1)(x-2)(x-3)+r(x)$$and, since $r(-1)=r(2)=r(3)=0$ and $\deg r(x)<3$, $r(x)=0$.

Comment: Typo on line 4: `>` should be `<`.

Comment: @NickD I've edited my answer. Thank you.